# mysql- sort list based on empty and null values as last in column

Tags: mysql

I have a table of users with basic details id, their names and profile photo (link to photo, actually)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userName` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `photo` varchar(50) NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=42 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `userName`,`photo`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 'John', 'john.png',1),
(2, 'Jane', 'jane.png',1),
(3, 'Ali', '',1),

(6, 'Bruce', 'bruce.png',1),

(7, 'Martha', '',1),
(8, 'Sidney', '',1),
(10, 'Charlie', 'charlie.png',1),

(12, 'Elisa', '',1),
(14, 'Samantha', 'samantha.png',1),
(15, 'Hannah', 'hannah.png',1),

(16, 'Hannah', '',1),
(17, 'Kevin', 'kevin1.png',1),
(18, 'Kevin', 'kevin2.png',1),
(19, 'Ruth', '',1);
```

Not all users have profile picture. I would like to list these users in alphabetic order and also show users who have profile picture in front.

This is the query that I wrote:

```
select * from users ORDER BY photo DESC ;
```

It sorts users based on photo value but they are not being shown in alphabetic order.

Is it possible to list these users such that all users who have photos will appear top on the list with [userName] in alphabetic order?

[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35a86e/1)

Comment: photo is NOT NULL. So everybody has a photo.

Comment: but some don't have a value. @Strawberry

Comment: I would suggest you amend your design to allow NULL in that column. `''` is not fun.

Comment: OK. II'll make that change but how to achieve the result after doing so. @Strawberry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have empty vlaues here. So you can use this way.

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY if(photo = '' or photo is null,1,0), userName
```

But in mysql has a method to order null values with (-).

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY -photo DESC, userName ASC
```

Here photo column data order as null values last because of DESC order

OR

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY
CASE WHEN photo IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC, userName ASC
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks! @Chandana Kumara

Answer (score 2):

Once you've changed `''` to NULL...

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY photo IS NULL,username;
```

Comment: See if you can figure that out for yourself

Answer (score 0):

If you want 1st people without picture and then other (while sorting these 2 groups alphabetically):

```
select * from users ORDER BY photo,userName ASC ;
```

Waiting your feed back if it is not exactly what you want.

Comment: I want people with picture first. @Thibault Leveau